# Extend/Custom IApplicationBuilder when running TestServer in a .NET Core 3.1 Web API unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to use a TestServer in a unit test for integration testing.

I'm currently using this code:

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
            {
                // Add TestServer
                webHost.UseTestServer();
                webHost.UseStartup<Startup>();

            });
```

which uses my default Startup implementation.

I want to call an additional function of IApplicationBuilder (in Startup.Configure) for my unit test.
What would be the best way to achieve this without boilerplate code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unit test specific [startup filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#extend-startup-with-startup-filters), and move call to your "additional function" to the filter.